# Logstash. Nested object mapping with ruby script

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a problem with nested object mapping by ruby filter plugin.
My object should have field cmds which is array of objects like this:

```
 "cmds": [
            {
              "number": 91,
              "errors": [],
              "errors_count": 0
            },
            {
              "number": 92,
              "errors": ["ERROR_1"],
              "errors_count": 1
            }]
```

By elasticsearch I need to find objects where ***number* = 91** and ***error_count* > 0**. So object above shoudn`t be correct result. But my query (below) matches it.

```
GET /logs/default/_search
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "cmds.number": 91
          }
        },
        {
         "range": {
           "cmds.errors_count": {
             "gt": 0

           }
         }
        }]}}
```

**I know it because [JSON document is flattened into a simple key-value format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)** and I should mapp the cmds field as type nested instead of type object.
The problem is I have no idea how to do it in my logstash ruby script with event.set

I have folowing code:

```
for t in commandTexts do

    commandv = Command.new(t)

    if i==0
        event.set("[cmds]", ["[number]" => commandv.hexnumber, 
                            "[command_text]" => commandv.command_text, 
                            "[errors]" => commandv.errors, 
                            "[has_error]" => commandv.has_error, 
                            "[errors_count]" => commandv.errors_count])      
    else
        event.set("[cmds]", event.get("cmds") + ["[number]" => commandv.hexnumber,
                                                 "[command_text]" => commandv.command_text, 
                                                 "[errors]" => commandv.errors,
                                                 "[has_error]" => commandv.has_error, 
                                                 "[errors_count]" => commandv.errors_count])

    end
    i+=1
   end
end
```

I`m new in ruby and my code is not perfect, but "cmds" field look fine in elastic search. The only problem is that is not nested. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it. I`m still new in ELK, and sometimes I'm confused where (logstash/kibana/scripts in ruby) i should do what needed.

My code is okey. Using kibana, I deleted my index, and make a new one with correct mapping

code:

```
PUT  /logs?pretty
{
  "mappings": {"default": {
"properties": {
  "cmds" : {
   "type" : "nested",
    "properties": {
              "command_text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "errors": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "errors_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "has_error": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "number": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }

  }
}
  }}

}
```

Earlier I was trying to create new index just by setting "type" as "nested"

```
  PUT  /logs?pretty
    {
      "mappings": {"default": {
    "properties": {
      "cmds" : {
       "type" : "nested"
      }


    }
    }}}
```

But it wasn`t working correctly ("cmds" field was not added to elasticsearch) so I done it by full mapping (all properties).